# How to implement user "auto-approval" with Forgerock OpenAM and OAuth2

Tags: openam, oauth-2.0

I want to use OpenAM as IAM platform. 
On the other hand I want to protect and provide fine-grained access to a layer of REST services using OAuth2 with OpenAM playing the role of OAuth2 Server / Provider.

This is working for me already, however in this case I would like the screen for the user to confirm access not to appear. The reason being is that in this case I'm not really using OAuth2 for delegation. At the end of the day I want my REST services layer to be protected. The user should not even realize that we are using OAuth2 for this purpose.

Is there an "auto-approval" feature (similar to the existing in Spring OAuth2 framework) to explicitly avoid the approval screen being shown to the user and approve automatically instead?
I had a look at the OpenAM documentation but I could not find anything..

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The recent release of OpenAM 13.5 has a new built-in option to "Allow clients to skip consent":

https://backstage.forgerock.com/#!/docs/openam/13.5/admin-guide#allowing-clients-to-skip-consent

Possibly too late for the asker, but may help others.

Answer (score 0):

You could pre-fill the 'consent saving' attributes with the value

> ClientID + blank + scope2 + blank + scope2 + blank + scopeN

This will make the 'consent page' not show up. I guess this is what you mean by 'approval screen'.

Comment: Thanks Bernhard for your answer. Yes, I meant the 'consent page'. I got some answers in the Forgerock community. One of them is exactly the workaround you suggested. I share the link so people interested in this subject can follow it. Thanks again! https://forgerock.org/topic/how-to-implement-user-auto-approval-with-forgerock-openam-and-oauth2/

Comment: the related OpenAM RFE is tracked as https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-5093